# Running An Erlang Escript File With SSL Distribution

Tags: erlang, erlang-escript

I have a little escript file that connects to a node and does some rpc calls and stuff...

It works fine for short or longnames but relies on standard http comms for distributed Erlang.

I would like to use it but with https/SSL for distribution.

To start a 'normal' Erlang system with SSL you have to pass in the various flags to tell Erlang to run that way, as the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html) suggests:

```
$ ERL_FLAGS="-boot \"/home/me/ssl/start_ssl\" -proto_dist inet_ssl 
  -ssl_dist_opt client_certfile \"/home/me/ssl/erlclient.pem\" 
  -ssl_dist_opt server_certfile \"/home/me/ssl/erlserver.pem\" 
  -ssl_dist_opt verify 1 -ssl_dist_opt depth 1"
$ export ERL_FLAGS
$ erl -sname ssl_test
```

This replaces the default distribution mechanism (`inet_tcp_dist`) with the ssl one (`inet_ssl_dist`).

[escript](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html) runs an erlang file as a shell scripting file.

My questions are:

- is it possible to get the Erlang 'environment' in which escript runs to use the secure distribution mechanism instead of the default one?
- and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to set these flags via the environment, you can also pass them directly to `erl`, see [ch. 1.4 here](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.2/lib/ssl-2.3.5/doc/html/ssl_distribution.html). `erl` flags can be passed to [escript](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html) via the `%%!` argument line.

---

**z.escript**

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -boot start_ssl -proto_dist inet_ssl -ssl_dist_opt client_certfile /home/me/ssl/erlclient.pem -ssl_dist_opt server_certfile /home/me/ssl/erlserver.pem -ssl_dist_opt verify 1 -ssl_dist_opt depth 1
main(_) ->
    io:format("~p~n", [init:get_arguments()]).
```

---

```
zed@zed:~$ ./z.escript 
[{root,["/opt/erlang-R13B03/lib/erlang"]},
 {progname,["erl"]},
 {home,["/home/zed"]},
 {boot,["start_clean"]},
 {noshell,[]},
 {boot,["start_ssl"]},
 {proto_dist,["inet_ssl"]},
 {ssl_dist_opt,["client_certfile","/home/me/ssl/erlclient.pem"]},
 {ssl_dist_opt,["server_certfile","/home/me/ssl/erlserver.pem"]},
 {ssl_dist_opt,["verify","1"]},
 {ssl_dist_opt,["depth","1"]}]
```

Comment: As ever Zoltan - you are on the money. I don't know how I missed that line in the escript documentation <-- damn fool!